# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax (Spring Hibernate)

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm just trying to run this tutorial project: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Doing the same, but getting an error:

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near '??' at line 1
```

What could be wrong here?

I'm using MySQL 8.0.15, SpringBoot 5, IntelliJ Idea

Comment: What code did you run when that error was thrown?

Comment: I tested the code using MySQL version 5.7 and i had to define `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` in properties to make it work. Can you try that one? otherwise you can change dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`

Comment: @CristianColorado Thank's! It works now :)